# Using the es6 spread operator in htmlbars

Tags: ember.js

Is is possible to use the equivalent of the spread operator in htmlbars?

```
let items = ['hello', 'world'];
someFunction(...items); // equivalent to someFunction('hello', 'world');
```

I need this in htmlbars

```
{{link-to 'some.route' ...items}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible afaik. I believe this PR request tries to implement it: https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/pull/1149. Unfortunately development on it doesn't seem to be very active.

Comment: OK, I actually got this specific scenario working anyway because link-to supports a `params` attribute. `{{link-to params=myParams}}`.