# Ember opposite of positionalParams

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, htmlbars

In an Ember Component it is possible to define a [positionalParams](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.LinkComponent.html#property_positionalParams) property so that parameters passed as positional params become available as properties. E.g:

```
let MyComponent = Ember.Component.extend;
MyComponent.reopenClass({
  positionalParams: ['name', 'age']
});
```

when it is invoked: `{{my-component "John" 38}}` the property `name` has the value `John` and de property `age` has the value `38`.

I would like to have the opposite behavior but I cannot find whether this is possible. The behavior I'm looking for is like following:

Instead of passing a number of positional params (`{{my-comp param1 param2}}`) I would like to pass an array property (`{{my-comp positionalArguments=myArray}}`) because it can be of a dynamic size.

I'm not only looking for this behavior at components, but also helpers: `{{ concat firstName " " lastName }}` should become `{{ concat positionalArguments=myArray }}`. The helper should get the same params-array as first argument in both cases.

Comment: `MyComponent` is using  `reopenClass` method for defining `positionalParams`. so this is specific to class `MyComponent`. I would say defining positionalParams dynamically its not possible.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE After my misunderstood is resolved:**

You want to have a [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator). You may look this discussions [1](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/12658), [2](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/1050). For now, you can get the array and do the assignment at init. Also have a look at this [SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36808963/using-the-es6-spread-operator-in-htmlbars).

**OLD Answer**

So don't use array brackets in your positional parameter definition:

```
let MyComponent = Ember.Component.extend;
MyComponent.reopenClass({
  positionalParams: 'myparams'
});
```

Use it like that:

```
{{my-component 2 'a' 'b'}}
{{my-component 2 'a' 'b' 4 'c' 7}}
```

Comment: I would like to use it the other way, by passing a property reference (which is an array) and it should be interpreted as the positional parameters.